# View hierarchy used by the Pages Mac OS X app

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I need to build a Mac OS X app which requires view hierarchy similar to the Pages app. I understand that their is a toolbar at the top. On the left is a scroll view that contains a custom view but I have problem figuring out the hierarchy on the right, specifically the scroll section used on the right which allows options to hide or show up dynamically depending on the other options.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is called an inspector view. It is not apart of the public SDK; this is all private code.

If you want to see how it's made start a view debugging session in xcode and attach it to the pages process. What you will find:

- Inspector View
- Inspector Pane Group view and Inspector Segmented Control
- Inspector Pane View and Inspector Pane Disclosure Views.

You can make this fairly quickly from existing UI views and controls.

Comment: a. Is there a way to find what Inspector View or other views extend? b. I still find it difficult to construct the dynamic UI -- very simply how do you provide more options when someone selects something other than No Fill. It will greatly help if you can suggest a view hierarchy for this.

Comment: I would implement that as an NSTabView and use an NSPopUpButton to select the tab index.